# Add content under right side of tabular environment

Tags: tables

In the skills section of my CV/Resume, I would like to add content to the right side of the tabular and keep it under the first line and organised. [image: Screen shot]

As can be seen in the image, I would like to have 'Highcharts, D3.js' directly under 'Tableau, Bash...'. The code that I am using is as follows;

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Computer Languages &  Python, R, Unix, JavaScript, HTML \\
Software \& Tools & Tableau,  Bash, Decision Trees, Support Vector Machine, Sci-kit learn, 

& HighCharts, D3.js \\

\end{tabular}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You missed to add \\ in your line starting with `Software`. Please -- as usual here -- do not add code snippets, show us a short compilable code resulting in your error ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. ! It looks like you are using a specific CV class. Whether I am right or not, please enlarge your MWE to make it fully compiliable. Add a preamble with your class and all the packages you need to compile your MWE (and just your MWE). Add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. We should be able to compile your MWE with a simple copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should change the last column type to `p{...}` and remove the last `\\`

Depending of the result you want:

- add `\\` after the penultimate line

  \documentclass{article}

  ```
  \usepackage{array}


  \begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} p{6cm}}
  Computer Languages &  Python, R, Unix, JavaScript, HTML \\
  Software \& Tools & Tableau,  Bash, Decision Trees, Support Vector Machine, Sci-kit learn\\
  & HighCharts, D3.js

  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

- or remove the last `&`

  ```
  \documentclass{report}


  \usepackage{array}


  \begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} p{6cm}}
  Computer Languages &  Python, R, Unix, JavaScript, HTML \\
  Software \& Tools & Tableau,  Bash, Decision Trees, Support Vector Machine, Sci-kit learn,
   HighCharts, D3.js 

  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]